# could you inform me what it is wrong? "VBA web login", it's not work

Tags: vba, authentication

[image]

I'm studying VBA for excel

now it is for crawling web by excel

i don't know what it is wrong.

could you tell me the solution?

```
private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Set ie = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")

  ie.Visible = True 
 ie.navigate "http://www.marso.co.kr/member/login.html"
Do
    If ie.readyState = 4 Then
        Exit Do
    Else
        DoEvents
    End If
Loop

   ie.Document.getElementById("member_id").Value = "11111"
   ie.Document.getElementById("member_passwd").Value = "11111"
 ie.Document.getElementsByClassName("btn_280_black").Click


End Sub
```

Comment: **it's  not work** is not a sufficient error description. Please click on [edit] to update your question with a description of the expected and actual behaviour of your code, error messages, etc. Then we might be able to help. I recommend to read [ask]  to learn more about asking good questions.

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

**Thanks to @plutian for the heads up in the comments**

Convert

```
ie.Document.getElementsByClassName("btn_280_black").Click
```

To

```
ie.Document.getElementsByClassName("btn_280_black")(0).Click
```

This needs to be done because [getElementsbyClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) returns an **Array** (even if only one Element was found).

### Old (not quite right) answer

I believe the issue you may be facing is as follows:

At this part

```
ie.Document.getElementById("member_id").Value = "11111"
ie.Document.getElementById("member_passwd").Value = "11111"
ie.Document.getElementsByClassName("btn_280_black").Click
```

You use Upper-case `Value` and `Click` while you should be using lower-case `value` & `click`.

Also your accessing of the button is a bit wrong, [getElementsbyClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) returns an **Array** (even if only one Element was found).

This means you need to access the first Element of said array by adding `[0]` to your button call => `ie.Document.getElementsByClassName("btn_280_black")[0].click`.

And finally, just accessing the button's .click function **won't call the function** so you'll need to call it by adding `()` to the end of your call, turning it into `ie.Document.getElementsByClassName("btn_280_black")[0].click()`

So at the end it should look more like this:

```
ie.Document.getElementById("member_id").value = "11111"
ie.Document.getElementById("member_passwd").value = "11111"
ie.Document.getElementsByClassName("btn_280_black")[0].click()
```

Hope this helps, if any errors pop up while trying this out, please add them to your reply.

Comment: You're close, but no cigar. Your syntax is off as VBA =/= HTML. But you did spot the error correctly: *getElementsbyClassName returns an Array*. The rest is irrelevant (upper-lower case). Proper syntax is `ie.Document.getElementsByClassName("btn_280_black")(0).Click`. Add that and it works fine.